# Adding a wrapper to contain tables using grouping field in views / display suite

Tags: views, theming

I'm using a table to display fields data in views 3. Within this i've got a field selected to group these items which produces a heading and then a table for each group. All good up to this point.
The issue i'm trying to solve is a way to manipulate all these tables - so i'd like to add a container, with an id to style accordingly.
I'm able to access the wrapper for the whole via https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21views-view.tpl.php/7
and the template for the table which in my instance is views-bootstrap-table-plugin-style.tpl.php (which allows me to markup for each table)
What i'm looking is where the loop occurs for the grouped field so i can put a wrapper round the loop. Any suggestions?

EDIT: here is a grab of my view https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2mb85m1lo2oxr4/views-display.png 
The region i am trying to wrap is below the exposed filters form.
I am using Display Suite > Views Displays to layout the view with exposed filters and views content in the left column and the map as an attachment in the right column.

EDIT: removing the view having its template defined via DS Views has given a result with markup with a .view-content wrapper around the tables (which is good) but isn't entirely helpful as i still need to split the view into two columns (which is why i was using DS).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7aukgjkkux2xycs/views-display-no-ds.png

Whilst creating a custom template to do this by modifying an existing DS template and making a region specifically for my grouped table seems the quickest way to solve this, it certainly seems a bit messy as this will need to be done for every time i set to use grouped fields.

Comment: So you want one wrapper around all your grouped tables?

Comment: thats exactly what i'm trying to do. so far i have the following:
h3
table
h3
table 
h3 
table

and would like to wrap it all in a div.

Answer (score 1):

You can add classed to your regions within Display suite:

Add CSS classes to regions
Now that you have defined regions you can define custom CSS classes for them.

- Go to Administration > Structure > Display Suite > CSS Classes (admin/structure/ds/classes)
- Enter custom class names in the fields "CSS classes for regions” (one per line). You can provide a human friendly class name by using a pipe ("|”), e.g.,:

  `class_name_1
  class_name_2|Class two
  extravagant|Extravagant
  subtle_emphasis|Subtle emphasis`
- Click "Save”
- Go to Administration > Structure > Display Suite (admin/structure/ds/layout) and choose "manage display” for the desired entity.
- Choose the tab "Custom classes” to assign the classes to the regions
- Click the tab "Extra classes for regions”. Assign the defined classes to the regions.
- Click "Save”
- You can check the source code of your web page to see the new classes and start styling them in your CSS.

From [Manage displays](https://www.drupal.org/node/1795294).

You can use above steps to add a class to your Display Suite region. Depending on how Views renders the View, explore the DOM to see if you need to select additional classes.

Comment: Very helpful although the notes don't quite match whats going on in that latest 2.* release of DS or actually solve my issue. It has lead to the solution being made by just creating a custom DS layout and assigning a specific region that i can drop my tables into allowing me to wrap it and scroll.